# Does RestSharp proxy per request have best practice?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

Since Restsharp  use HttpClient from version v107 it can cause SocketOverflow exception if you open alot of connection. What is best practice to use RestSharp when you need parse alot of responses with different proxy per request as fast as possible ( Example - Validate proxy list )

Additional: Should i use Threading instead Task in this case?

Please note:
https://www.proxy-listen.de/azenv.php - is proxy judge which return your ip behind proxy.

The reason why i use RestSharp instead pure HttpClient is Exceptions, if proxy invalid - httpClient throw exception which break performance very well.

Current version : v108

My example with creating alot of RestClients :

```
 public async Task Validate()
        {
            //For this example, proxyList.txt contains 50000 proxies with format Host:Port .
            List<string> listProxy = (await File.ReadAllLinesAsync("proxyList.txt")).ToList();

            //Fill tasks
            var tasks = new List<Task<RestResponse>>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= listProxy.Count; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                 {
                     // Set the proxy for this request
                     var proxySplit = listProxy[i].Split(':');
                     var proxy = new WebProxy(
                         $"socks5://{proxySplit[0]}:{proxySplit[1]}");

                     var client = new RestClient(
                         new RestClientOptions()
                     {
                             MaxTimeout = 5000,
                             Proxy = proxy
                     });
                     
                     var request = new RestRequest("https://www.proxy-listen.de/azenv.php", Method.Get);
                     return await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
                 }));
            }

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
           
            foreach (var task in tasks.Where(x => x.IsCompletedSuccessfully == true))
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await task;
                    Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Bad");
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }
```

So any advices how can HttpClient problem can bypassed?

More information about it - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35992

Comment: I don't know if it is related but `SOCKS5` proxy is enabled in .net6 onwards.

Comment: @Eldar, Ye, since .net6 microsoft enable socks proxy support, but question is about how to properly create/use/dispose RestClient with random proxy for every request and bypass socket limitation, this problem is very known in dotnet (see related link to github.com/issue) when most of languages such as Python doesn't have problem with it  and can add Proxy/Cookie/Session for Request object (not Client Object) and bypass socket leakage, we in .Net can add Proxy/CookieContainer/Session only to Client which create alot of problems, such as impossibility create rotating-proxy service and etc.

Comment: In theory, using a proxy per request is the same as creating a new `HttpClient` because it requires a new connection. And for the `HttpClient` it is held by the `HttpClientHandler` so you will need that many handlers.  As in your question 50k connections and tasks is not feasible to create at once. You need to set some limitations (CPU and connection ). You can use `Sempahore` kind of constructs to limit them.

Comment: If you are using paid proxies you can choose a proxy provider that rotates those addresses for you. It gives you one proxy address and it redirects you to a different IP with every request. If you want to rotate the cookie container too you can hold the `HttpClientHandler` instances and assign a new `CookieContainer` before the request.